# Show markers on one Google Map using values from two different tables

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Here is my code. It reads latitude and longitude from a database table and adds markers onto the map. What I want to do is to add another table in it and add different-colored markers according to its latitude and longitude values on the *same map*. I do not know how to take latitude and longitude from two different tables and show on map with different-color markers.

```
function initialize() {
    <?php echo "initializing: ";?>
    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(39.40233290,77.89265660 );
    var image = {
        url: 'images/image.png',
        // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 32 pixels high.
        size: new google.maps.Size(30, 32)
    };

    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 10,
        center: position,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    <?php       
    $sql="select latitude,longitude FROM coffeeshop ";
    $records = mysql_query($sql, $conn);
    if (!$records) {
        echo "Could not successfully run query ($sql) from DB: " . mysql_error();
        exit;
    }

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($records)) {
        ?>
        var lat= <?php echo $row['latitude'] ?>;
        var long=<?php echo $row['longitude'] ?>;
        addMarker(lat,long);
        <?php echo $row['longitude'];
    }
    ?>

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;  

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        map: map,
        title:"This is the place."
    });  

    var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        map: map,
        icon: image,
        title:"This is the place."
    });  

    var contentString = 'Hello <strong>World</strong>!';
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
        geocodeLatLng(geocoder, map, infowindow);
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.open(map,marker2);
        geocodeLatLng(geocoder, map, infowindow);
    });

    function addMarker(lat,long) {
        var latlongMarker = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,long);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlongMarker, 
            map: map,            
        }); 

        var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlongMarker, 
            map: map,
            icon:image,            
        }); 

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.open(map,marker);
            geocodeLatLng(geocoder, map, infowindow,marker);     
        });
    }    
}
```

Comment: You only have one query that selects from one table... How do you expect to get the data from a 2nd table without selecting from it? What is your problem exactly?

Comment: This is what I need. Query that takes values from 2nd table as well with different markers and where should I place that query in this code.

Comment: We cannot possibly help you write a query for a table we have no knowledge of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use ajax, to get the values no the mysql functions.

With ajax you can get data from certain php method. This method can gather all data needed from db (in you case from two tables) and prepare it as one array (you have to encode it to json to get it via ajax).

Also code will be cleaner, as you don't mess php with javascript.